# Why is my java object not created as intended?

Tags: java

```
public class Object
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Player p1 = new Player(1,true,false);
        System.out.println(p1);
    }
}

class Player
{
    public int id;
    public boolean split;
    public boolean spill;

    public Player(int id,boolean split,boolean spill)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.split = split;
        this.spill = spill;
    }

    public int getId(){return id;}
    public Boolean isSplit(){return split;}
    public Boolean isSpill(){return spill;}
    public void setSplit(Boolean s){this.split=s;}
    public void setSpill(Boolean s){this.spill=s;}

    public String toString(){return "id:"+id+"|split:"+split+"|spill:"+spill;}
}
```

Why does this output?

```
id:1|split:false|spill:false
```

It outputs the intended output when I make sure the argument name is different from the instance property.

(i.e split,this.split=split in the constructor)

Edit: corrected a typo in the arguments of my constructor. My original argument names are split and spill. I changed it to spl and spi to test different argument name and forgot to change it back.

Comment: Hint: what are your parameter names in the constructor? How many of those parameters do you actually refer to?

Comment: Try Lombok! And use the @AllArgsConstructor annotation above the class. You will love it

Comment: Your edited code actually produces `id:1|split:true|spill:false` ... so there is nothing to explain.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Player(int id,boolean spl,boolean spi)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.split = split;
        this.spill = spill;
    }
```

You should correct this to

```
public Player(int id,boolean split,boolean spill)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.split = split;
        this.spill = spill;
    }
```

In the version of your code, this.split and split are the same boolean variable, autoinitialized to `false`.

Comment: My mistake, the 2nd code you gave is my original code. I was doing some testing and I forgot to change the spli back to split and spi to spill.

Comment: @LinnHtetAung do not edit the original question in this way...